# PHP array to XML cdata

Tags: php, soap

I would like to add CDATA to an array to create xml element "data" which contains unescaped characters (&,<,> for example).

```
  $array['data'] = [
        'data_1' => [
          'key' => $key,
          'date' => date('c', time()),
          'data' => '<!CDATA>dfa</CDATA>'
        ]
      ];
    }
```

It's about data value. In WSDL it's defined as

```
<s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="data">
 <s:complexType mixed="true">
   <s:sequence>
    <s:any/>
   </s:sequence>
 </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

So the question is: how can I set unescaped characters/how to add CDATA to an array which gets passed as a parameter to SoapClient?